# Как сделать изображение на всю площадь контейнера

Tags: html, css, css3

Как можно сделать так что б img занимал всю площадь div?

```
<div class="block">
    <img src="assets/content-image-2.jpg" alt="image-2">
</div>
```

background не подходит

Comment: и почему же не подходит?

Comment: @teran в моем случае это не удобно ,я уверен есть более рациональный подход

Comment: чем это может быть не удобно? какая разница в какой атрибут вы впишите путь к картинке?

Comment: @teran при адаптивной верстке это не лучший подход

Answer (score 0):

можно еще в сторону `object-fit` посмотреть

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/163/15/10/Depositphotos_213571854_m-2015_d_850.jpg" alt="image-2">
</div>
```

Comment: и если блок по высоте больше чем картинка то что?

Comment: а как можно сделать что б изображение обрезалось ?

Comment: @Vanya, так изображение и обрезается (картинка на самом деле больше) - через `overflow: hidden`, но я бы советовал посмотреть вам в сторону `object-fit` - посмотрите ссылку, которую я добавил в ответ

Comment: @teran, тогда лучше смотреть в сторону `object-fit` и использовать `object-fit: cover;`

Comment: @Zhihar object-fit отказывается работать к сожалению ,размер контейнера должен быть в пикселях?

Comment: @Vanya, нет - в любых единицах, которые css понимает, а почему отказывается работать? посмотрите тогда еще и для разных браузеров - типа -o-object-fit, -moz-object-fit и т.п. (поищите в сети) - http://htmlbook.ru/css/-o-object-fit

Answer (score -1):

```css
.block{
   position: relative;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden
   
}

.block img{
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <img src="https://masyamba.ru/%D0%A1%D0%9D%D0%95%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%98/77-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8.jpg" alt="image-2">
</div>
```

Comment: кому интересно смотреть на изображение  с кривыми пропорциями?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Есть прямой вопрос : как заполнить картинкой весь блок.
А зачем это - отдельный разговор.